# SQL Server Connection in R

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using R but getting error

library(DBI)
library(odbc)

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       Driver   = "SQL Server",
                       Server   =  "CNV***\\R***" ,
                       Trusted_Connection = "True")
```

**error snippet**

**Error**

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 01000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).

But when I change to different server the connection get **established**

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       Driver   = "SQL Server",
                       Server   =  "XYZ***" ,
                       Trusted_Connection = "True")
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error , I would appreciate if someone could suggest what could be the reason or someone faced similar error and how to resolve.

Comment: This seems to be caused by a server using. TSL 1.0 rather than a later version. This [link](https://www.sqlnethub.com/blog/dbnetlib-connectionopen-secdoclienthandshake-ssl-security-error-resolve/) seems to suggest a method to bypass this limitation, however once never encountered this society problem myself.

Comment: The accepted answer here solved this for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637713/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-2008-using-odbc-connection-via-system-dsn-on-win